# Free Ultrafilter limits

Tags: set-theory, filters, baire-category

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a free ultrafilter on $\mathbf{N}$ containing the even integers, and $(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ be the $\{0,1\}$-valued sequence such that $x_n=1$ if and only if $n$ is even. Then $(x_n)$ is $\mathscr{F}$-convergent to $1$.

> **Question.** Identifying a sequence $(n_k) \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbf{N}}$ with infinitely many $1$s with a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$, is it true that the set of subsequences 
>   $$
> \{(n_k) \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbf{N}}: x_{n_k} \text{ is }\mathscr{F}\text{-convergent to }0\}
> $$
>   is of first Baire category?

Edit: an equivalent formulation, identifying the set $S$ is strictly increasing sequences in $\mathbf{N}$ with the set of sequences in $\{0,1\}^{\mathbf{N}}$ with infinitely many $1$s:

> **Question.** If $\mathscr{F}$ is a free ultrafilter containing $2\mathbf{N}$, is it true that $\{(n_k) \in S: \{k \in \mathbf{N}: n_k \text{ odd }\}\in \mathscr{F}\}$ is meager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me simplify your problem first: we may replace the set of even natural numbers to the whole $\mathbb{N}$. Moreover, for given $f:\mathbb{N}\to 2$, $f$ is $\mathcal{F}$-convergent to zero iff $f^{-1}[\{0\}]\in \mathcal{F}$. Therefore, our problem is equivalent to asking whether $A_\mathcal{F}^0:=\{f \in 2^\omega \mid f^{-1}[\{0\}]\in \mathcal{F}\}$ is meager.

The answer is negative: observe that $2^\omega$ is a disjoint union of $A_\mathcal{F}^0$ and $A_\mathcal{F}^1:=\{f \in 2^\omega \mid f^{-1}[\{1\}]\in \mathcal{F}\}$.
Furthermore, the map $\phi:2^\omega\to 2^\omega$ defined by
$$\phi(f)(n)=1-f(n)$$
is a homeomorphism over $2^\omega$ which sends $A_\mathcal{F}^0$ to $A_\mathcal{F}^1$ bijectively. Hence if $A_\mathcal{F}^0$ is meager then so does $A_\mathcal{F}^1$, so $2^\omega$ is a union of two meager sets, a contradiction.

---

There were misunderstanding on the question, and the OP asks the set
$$A_1=\{f\in S \mid f^{-1}[2\mathbb{N}+1]\in\mathcal{F}\}$$
is meager or not (where $S$ is the set of all increasing functions from $\omega$ to $\omega$. I assume that the topology is given as the subspace topology of $\omega^\omega$.)

The answer is still negative by the similar argument: observe that $f^{-1}[2\mathbb{N}+1]\cup f^{-1}[2\mathbb{N}]=\mathbb{N}$, so one of $f^{-1}[2\mathbb{N}+1]$ or $f^{-1}[2\mathbb{N}]$ must be a member of $\mathcal{F}$.

Now assume that the set $A_1$ is meager. We can see that the map $\phi(f)= f+1$ is an embedding from $S$ to itself. Moreover, $\phi[A_1]\supseteq\{f\in S\mid f(0)\ge 1\land f^{-1}[2\mathbb{N}]\in\mathcal{F}\}$. (This follows from $(g+1)^{-1}[2\mathbb{N}+1]=g^{-1}[2\mathbb{N}]$, and $f=g+1$ if $f(0)\ge 1$ for increasing $f$.)

Therefore, the set $\{f\in S \mid f(0)\ge 1\}$ is covered by two meager sets, namely $A_1$ and $\phi[A_1]$. However, this is impossible as $\{f\in S \mid f(0)\ge 1\}$ is a non-empty open set of $S$.

Comment: Let $S$ be the claimed set. Then $(n_k) \in S$ iff $\{k: x_{n_k}=0\} \in \mathscr{F}$ iff $\{k: n_k \text{ is odd}\} \in \mathscr{F}$. Accordingly, your function $\phi$ is still a homeomorphism. But why $\phi[A_{\mathscr{F}}^0]=A_{\mathscr{F}}^1$? To be explicit, if you assume that $\{k: n_k \text{ is odd}\} \in \mathscr{F}$, how do you conclude that $\{k: t_k \text{ is even}\} \in \mathscr{F}$, where $(t_k)=\phi((n_k))$ is the "complementary" sequence of $(n_k)$?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti I feel your notation bit confusing; the function $k\mapsto n_k$ sends a natural number to 0 or 1, as far as I understand. Then is it meaningful to mention $x_{n_k}$? I vaguely understand your question (to be honest), so please let me know if my understanding seems incorrect.

Comment: Roughly speaking, $\phi$ in my proof "inverses" the value of sequences, and the value of $f$ is almost 0 or 1. If $f$ is almost 0, then $\phi(f)$ must be almost 1, and vice versa. This shows $\phi[A^0_\mathcal{F}]=A^1_\mathcal{F}$. Formally, it can be shown by observing $(\phi(f))^{-1}\{0\}=f^{-1}\{1\}$.

Comment: The "implicit" assumption is that the set of infinite subsets of $\mathbf{N}$ can be identified with $\{0,1\}^{\mathbf{N}}$ with infinitely many $1$ (which in turn can be identified with the set of subsequences $(x_{n_k})$ of a given sequence $(x_n)$). I don't know if this may have caused confusion in the notation. Anyway, I try to be more explicit: if $\mathscr{F}$ is a free ultrafilter containing $2\mathbf{N}$, is it true that $\{(n_k) \text{ increasing sequence in } \mathbf{N}: \{k: n_k \text{ odd }\}\in \mathscr{F}\}$ is meager?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti I cannot find a relation between your original question and your explicit statement. Anyway, to be answer your question, the set $\{f \text{ increasing} \mid f^{-1}[2\Bbb{N}+1] \in\mathcal{F}\}$ is not meager by the similar argument. I will edit my post to give a proof of it.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti I putted my proof. I was up all night (I posted the answer at 4 AM in my local time) so I have to go to take a nap... I am still willing to answer your question, but it could be delayed.

Comment: Everything works fine, good job Hanul (it is time to sleep also for me) :)